# Android Wear sends message to android mobile

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm new in Android Wear development. I'm trying to make the smartwatch send a string to a mobile app but I don't know how make it work. I've tried to do that following some tutorials, but still nothing works.

**Android mobile manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="manuela.com.messagewearableandroid">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ListenerService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Android Wear manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="manuela.com.messagewearableandroid">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**ListenerService for mobile**:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        showToast(messageEvent.getPath());
        System.out.println("Arrivato");
    }
    private void showToast(String message) {

        System.out.println("Arrivato");
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity for Wear**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initApi();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_toast);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
             * Sets up the button for handling click events.
             */
            sendToast();

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Initializes the GoogleApiClient and gets the Node ID of the connected device.
 */
private void initApi() {
    client = getGoogleApiClient(this);
    retrieveDeviceNode();
}


/**
 * Returns a GoogleApiClient that can access the Wear API.
 * @param context
 * @return A GoogleApiClient that can make calls to the Wear API
 */
private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
}

/**
 * Connects to the GoogleApiClient and retrieves the connected device's Node ID. If there are
 * multiple connected devices, the first Node ID is returned.
 */
private void retrieveDeviceNode() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result =
                    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await();
            List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
            if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}

/**
 * Sends a message to the connected mobile device, telling it to show a Toast.
 */
private void sendToast() {
    if (nodeId != null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(client, nodeId, MESSAGE, null);
                System.out.println("Mandato");
                client.disconnect();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Actually nothing happens, both the wear and the mobile simulators start, I push the button on the wear side but the toast doesn't appear on the mobile side.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) for *Sending and Receiving Messages*. You send messages using the [MessageApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html) and attach the following items to the message:

- An arbitrary payload (optional)
- A path that uniquely identifies the message's action

Here's another reference for [Sending String from watch to phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674808/sending-string-from-watch-to-phone).